# PHP MySQLi prepared statement not working as expected when called from function

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have the following code in delete_thread.php:

```
<?php
  include_once 'mysqli.php';

  $query = 'DELETE FROM Thread
            WHERE thread_id = ?';
  $delete_thread_statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);
  $delete_thread_statement->bind_param('i', $delete_thread_id);

  $query = 'DELETE FROM Reaction
            WHERE thread_id = ?';
  $delete_reactions_statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);
  $delete_reactions_statement->bind_param('i', $delete_thread_id);

  function delete_thread($thread_id){
    global $delete_thread_id;
    global $delete_thread_statement;
    global $delete_reactions_statement;

    $delete_thread_id = $thread_id;
    $delete_thread_statement->execute();
    $delete_reactions_statement->execute();

    $GLOBALS['rg']->addView($thread_id);
  }


?>
```

When I call delete_thread from another file (that has included the delete_thread.php file of course), the given thread id's are output (see last line of the function) to the page, but the corresponding records are not deleted.

Do you have any idea what's wrong?

Comment: You are binding "i" before it's actually set. `bind_param` should be in the function.

Comment: @rlanvin Thats not true. You can bind first and define the variable after.

Comment: What really should be asked - why you define statements outisde a function?

Comment: If you want some structure like this, then enclose it in a class, don't have random bits of strings in the global space and then include them in a function using `global`.

Comment: this is a very odd structure. Why not just put it all in the function?

Comment: @u_mulder because I want to re-use them, that's kinda the point of prepared statements iirc

Comment: if they're in the function they're still re-usable because the function itself is re-usable